# Find a basis for, and the dimension of, Ker(T) and Im(T)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:\mathbb R^{2*2}\to\mathbb R^{2*2}$ be a mapping with the form
$$T(M)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}M \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
Find a basis for, and the dimension of, $Ker(T)$ and $Im(T)$

Here is what I did:
Since M must be a 2 by 2 matrix, let $M=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$.
$$T(M)=\begin{pmatrix} b & b \\ b & b \end{pmatrix}$$

$$T=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
Thus, $dim(ker(T))=1$, basis:$(-1,1)^T$
$dim(Im(T))=1$, basis:$(1,0)^T$
Am I right?

Comment: I'm very confused about how your mapping is defined.

Comment: If you are trying to make matrices, the code `$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}.$$` produces the following:$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: No. Take a good look at your $T$. What's the domain and codomain?

Comment: From $T(M)$, as you have computed it, you should be able to read off the elements of both the kernel and the image. Your dimensions are not both correct. Additionally, the kernel and image should both be subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$, which the bases you give are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You have to keep in mind that the dimension of the domain of $T$ is equal to the sum between the dimensions of $\ker(T)$ and $im(T)$.

First let's calculate $\ker(T)$ and its dimension: if $T(M)=0$ then $b=0$. So

$$\ker(T)=\left\{\left[\begin{matrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{matrix}\right]: b=0\right\}=\left\{\left[\begin{matrix}a & 0 \\ c & d\end{matrix}\right]:a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}\right\}=<\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right], \left[\begin{matrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{matrix}\right], \left[\begin{matrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right]>,$$

and therefore $dim(\ker(T))=3$.

For other hand, you saw that $im(T)$ is generated by $\left[\begin{matrix}1&1\\1&1\end{matrix}\right]$. Hence $dim(im(T))=1$.

Answer (score 1):

You have, correctly, that $T(M)= \begin{pmatrix}b & b \\ b & b \end{pmatrix}$.  The "kernel" of T is the set of all matrices M such that $T(M)= \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ so clearly we need b= 0.  that is, $M= \begin{pmatrix}a & 0 \\c & d\end{pmatrix}= a\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}+ c\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}+ d\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ so the kernel has dimension 3.

The "image" is the set of all matrices $\begin{pmatrix}b & b \\ b & b \end{pmatrix}= b\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and so has dimension 1.